# Angular PATCH Method not allowed

Tags: typescript, http, angular6

Using the latest Angular

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.0
@schematics/update                0.6.0
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

I am studying the angular and exploring the different `http` requests like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and now the `PATCH`.

but I am having a problem when I am using the `PATCH` method, I just copy the `PUT` method and just change the `PUT` to `PATCH`, because I thought they are just have a same parameters and function.
but I encounter an error:

[image]

**`service.ts`**

```
const heroesUrl = "api/heroes";
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

patchHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.patch(heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`patched hero id=${hero.id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('patchHero'))
    );
}
```

**`component.ts`**

```
update(id: number, name: string): void {
    this.heroService.patchHero({id, name } as Hero)
        .subscribe(() => { 
        console.log("Success update") // This log is printing even if the Method not allow is appeared.
    });
}
```

I am just working and practicing the angular of the given tutorial from it site.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in this case isn't related to Angular itself, but the use of the `angular-in-memory-web-api` package that is used to serve mock data to the application. It simply doesn't have the `PATCH` method implemented, and is thus not allowed to use.

What you can do however is to implement the method yourself, as described [in the documentation of the package](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#http-method-interceptors).

In the `InMemoryDataService` class in `in-memory-data.service.ts` you can define a `patch(request: RequestInfo): Observable<Response>` method to handle your request.

A simple check with the following code should print out the console message!

```
patch(request: RequestInfo): Observable<Response> {
  console.log('This is inside your custom patch method!');
  return null;
}
```

This is obviously not a complete implementation of a `PATCH` method, but since the question isn't really about that I suggest that you look up the differences between a `PUT` and a `PATCH` and see if you can come up with it yourself! *(Hint, use `PUT` but remember to include the data that you aren't patching as well!)*

[Here's an example with the `PATCH` interceptor!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guyopo)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem about sending empty **Headers**.

Can you try this to append a header to your options:

```
let _headers = new HttpHeaders();
_headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const httpOptions = {
    headers: _headers
};
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but this isn't at all related to Angular itself but with the package that is used in the tutorial to serve mock data. See my example  [here!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-guyopo)

Answer (score 0):

Daniel B had it right. What is below is to fill in some details.

The patch method is not planned to be supported by `angular-in-memory-web-api` per this GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/115)

For reference I added the patch method in my `in-memory-data.service.ts` file with something like this.

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    patch(requestInfo: RequestInfo): Observable<Response> {
        const body = createBody(requestInfo);
        const responseOptions: ResponseOptions = {
            headers: requestInfo.headers,
            url: requestInfo.url,
            body,
            status: STATUS.OK,
            statusText: getStatusText(STATUS.OK),
        }
        return requestInfo.utils.createResponse$(() => responseOptions);
    }
}
```